Why won't Bazel creating symlinks during the build process?
From the directory with the WORKSPACE file I'm building a java target in bazel that should leave all the symlinks:
bazel build --symlink_prefix=bazel --experimental_convenience_symlinks=ignore //path/to/dir:JavaTarget

but it won't create the symlinks. I've removed the .bazelrc file and set the current and parent directories to chmod 777. I can't figure out why it isn't creating the links.

The documentation for --experimental_convenience_symlinks=ignore says:
"ignore: Symlinks will be left alone"
https://bazel.build/reference/command-line-reference#flag--experimental_convenience_symlinks
But the source code says something more specific:
    /** Will not create or clean up any symlinks. */
    IGNORE,

https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/blob/38ade70fed4b34043d21a606717ad2ed1ee9c696/src/main/java/com/google/devtools/build/lib/buildtool/BuildRequestOptions.java#L506-L507
So try not specifying --experimental_convenience_symlinks to leave it at the default value of normal.

Wow, yep, that was it. That is wildly confusing language. Thank you.

Clarified the docs here: https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/commit/064af35db4658f8d4da4c0e3aa3d4ad77c6f8401
